# Get all users under an user and those reporting under them in apex

Tags: apex, soql

i am looking for capturing all users under a user and all of them under them as well.

For example

If the current user is CEO then he should get to see all the people reporting to him and also the users reporting to these users.

What would be the SOQL query to get this list.

I can get the users directly reporting using this query

```
SELECT id, name from user where managerid=: userinfo.getUserId()
```

**EDIT**

@Mariia Illarionova answer does solve my issue, just for the sake of information, how do we handle multiple levels?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you need only 2 layers of sub users: actual children and actual grandchildren.

You can manage it with your slightly modified SOQL query:

```
SELECT Id FROM User WHERE ManagerId = :UserInfo.getUserId() OR Manager.ManagerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
```

Comment: This should work in my case. if we need to go further levels then add further or conditions manager.manager.manager.id?

Comment: Close, it would be `Manager.Manager.ManagerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()`